# Shipping & Handling not showing in magento 2.3.2 on frontend?

Tags: shipping, magento2.3.2

Is shipping & Handling not showing in Magento 2.3.2 on the frontend and in the order placed email also?

shipping price calculated but not show on the customer dashboard my orders

PFA
[image]

**Admin site showing properly**

[image]

Comment: post admin screenshot for the same order.

Comment: @Nidheesh check question

Comment: Any custom extensions for modifying the shipping rates?

Comment: not any extension  use but I have debugged it and we have to find Magecomp_Gstcharge extension issue

Comment: when I have add GST Rate, HSN Code for the product then shipping and handling not showing

Comment: Please check whether your product has weight or not? Also please check whether you enable shipping method or not? Your product should not be virtual product

Comment: yes I have checked all cases

Comment: I believe thats a paid extension. Check for their support, or upload the important files to your github and provide the link to check if thats a problem with that extension